# How can I tell whether "c" should be pronounced like "s" or like "k"?

Tags: pronunciation, letters-of-the-alphabet

How can I tell whether "c" should be pronounced "s" or "k"? I always get confused and pronounce it like "s" because it looks like russian "с".

Comment: Although I've never had to learn English as a second language, I imagine its vast array of pronunciation variations serves as one of the chief difficulties. I would also imagine that mastering all the pronunciations would yield an immense sense of personal pride and satisfaction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> *ca* → *k*
> *co* → *k*
> *cu* → *k*
> *ci* → *s*
> *ce* → *s*
> *cy* → *s*
> *c* at the end of a word → *k*
> *c* before *L* or *R* or *T* → *kl* or *kr* or *kt*  (ex. *cl*ap, *cr*oss, conne*ct*)

---

> *ch* at the beginning of a word **and** followed by a vowel → usually as in *chalk, children* (Ч in Russian)
> *ch* in the middle of a word (ex. *echo, archaic*) → usually *k*
> *ch* at the end of a word (ex. each, much) → almost always as in *chalk, children* (Ч in Russian)
> *ch* followed by an *r* → *kr*

---

> *tch* → **very** similar to *chalk, children*. look up examples and listen. If you pronounce it the same as *chalk* or *children* you will be approximately correct.

---

> *ck* → *k* (*c* is essentially silent)

*C* can also be pronounced as *sh* sometimes, but this is rare. It is most often found in adjectives ending in *-cious*, such as *conscious, precious, ferocious,* etc, and also in adjectives ending in *-cial*, such as *special, artificial, crucial, social,* etc. One major exception where *c* is pronounced as *sh* is the word *ocean.*

There are many other exceptions to the above rules. You will learn them as you go.

As Jim points out, an excellent rule of thumb is "Except for *ci, ce,* and *cy,* it's pronounced as a ***k***." With the exception of *ch*, of course.

---

<sub>There's also one or two words in English that begin with *cn*, in which case the *c* is completely silent. But they're very, very rare scientific words. There's also at least one that begins with *cth*, in which case the *c* is again silent.</sub>

Comment: What about cu -> k?  This answer reminds me of this clip: http://www.traileraddict.com/clip/my-life-in-ruins/sweaters

Comment: Oh god, I forgot a vowel. Oh god. Everyone stay away, it could spread.

Comment: I don't think *He* is likely to care.  I just found it amusing that most of the elaboration is unnecessary.  ca, co, cu, cl, cr, ct, c at the end of a word, and ch (except when pronounced like *children* all fall nicely into into *if it's not ci,ce, or cy it's pronounced 'k'*.

Comment: Jim, imma let you in on a little secret... *I did it for the rep points.*

Comment: Nice. I may have to try that some time.

Comment: *"C can also be pronounced as sh sometimes, but I can't think of a rule for this"* `C` can be pronounced as `sh` in the following word: `cache`.

Comment: That's *ch* pronounced as *sh*, which is another exception, not *c* pronounced as *sh* as in *artificial*. Without a rule, it's not too helpful to just name the word at random, I think.

Comment: There is no difference between the two *ch* versions of *children* and *catch*: the *t* is just an orthographic convention. It changes nothing here.

Comment: At the beginning of a word: chalk, children; but: character, chasm, chiral, ...  Loosely speaking, if it is of Greek origin, then k; Anglo-Saxon: tch.

Comment: Here is another exemption: crustacean

Comment: LOL I was looking at the first *c* for like 60 seconds trying to figure out how on earth that was an exception, until it hit me.

Comment: I think that cnidarian can also be pronounced as "kn", not necessarily silent

Comment: another exception is coe from coelenterate, where it is pronounced as s

Comment: The "sh" type exceptions can be formalised as: ci + another vowel = sh + vowel (again, with rare exceptions)

Comment: @tchrist years later I've learned the wording I needed to express the subtle difference between *children* and *catch*....in Hindi they have two sets of consonants, an aspirated version and a non-aspirated version of each. We don't really draw this distinction in English but for some words *it is nonetheless there*. I would argue that *catch* is aspirated while *children* is not. It is the same as the difference between the *p* in *pin* and the *p* in *spin.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant

Comment: "There's also at least one that begins with cth, in which case the c is again silent" - *ahem* - Cthulhu

Comment: "ck → k (c is essentially silent)" ... How do you know it's not the k that's silent? :)

Answer (score 7):

Pretty much if *c* is followed by *i, e, or y* it's pronounced like *s*. Otherwise it's pronounced like *k* (except sometimes when it's followed by *h* and is pronounced like *chalk* or *children*)
It can also sound like "sh" as in *artificial*.
There are always exceptions like *arciform* where it is pronounced like *k*, but overall I think it's not a bad rule of thumb.

Comment: @bytebuster- I changed the example word back to *arciform* because it properly demonstrates the exception '*c followed by i* sounding as *k'*.  Your suggestion of *architecture* is a '*c followed by h*' and is already covered by the '*otherwise it's pronounced like* **k**' clause.  Thanks for the other typo fixes though.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to know if "c"
and "k" sound the same?
Think of some words like
cliff, kitten, kettle,
computer, camera, like.
Pronounce these words
and you will notice that
both "c" and "k" are
pronounced the same as
"k".

It is the same case if "c"
and "k" are put together
and are pronounced as "k"
- click, pluck, tickle, lucky,
kick, yuck, wicker (and
many words that have "c"
and "k" together).

The difference between "c"
and "k" is:

- "C" is pronounced as "s" if it goes with the vowel letters, e and i.
- The rest of the vowel letters goes with c and they are pronounced as
  "k".

AEIOU

- Ca = pronounced as k  Example: California
- Ce = pronounced as s Example: Center
- Ci = pronounced as s Example: City
- Co = pronounced as k Example: Coke
- Cu = pronounced as k Example: Cup

Want to review?

- How to pronounce "circus" ? You can notice two c's in the word
  "circus". The first c is pronounced as "s" and the second c is
  pronounced as "k".

As for the letter "k", it has
no other pronunciation,
just "k". But be careful
when the letter "k" goes
with the letter "n" - know,
knife, knowledge, knight.
In this case, "k" is not
pronounced.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. As you see, attention to formatting, using the tools above the Answer box and reviewing the results in the display below it, can improve the readability of your answer.